# Format number as percent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have written this code and I want to format the number z as percent.

```
float l = ([textField2.text floatValue]);
float g = ([textField1.text floatValue]);

float x = l/1.23;
float y = x-g;
float z = y/l;

label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.2f \%",z];
```

Answer (score 6):

Make your code as follows.

```
label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.2f %%",(z*100)];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];

[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];  //optional
....

NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.435];

NSLog(@"%@", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number] );
```

43,50 %

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `%%` in order to print a percent sign in a format string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i want to format the number from float to percent.